# A function to convert minute since midnight to am/pm time

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Is there an existing android or java or joda-time function for converting minutes since midnight to time? I know how to do it for a 24 hour period without the am/pm bit. But I need to have the am/pm for some users.

This is for an android app. So the added benefit of using a standard function is that it will conform to the general preference of the user.

I suppose I can roll out my (buggy) own if such does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get that. Something like,

```
static DateFormat _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
static String minutesSinceMidnight(int minutes) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    return _sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar -- but you should also set Calendar.SECOND and Calendar.MILLISECOND or results may not be what you expect.